# Quartz.Net Trigger

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have to create a scheduler in c# that **fires every second week at Monday and Friday on 11:30 A.M**.I found Quartz.Net is good for making the scheduler application.
Now my problem is that I don't know how to create a trigger with my criteria.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a trigger that does that out of the box. You'll have to implement your own trigger to do this. You can start by inheriting from [AbstractTrigger](https://github.com/jvilalta/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/Impl/Triggers/AbstractTrigger.cs).

Take a look at the [CalendarInterval](https://github.com/jvilalta/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/Impl/Triggers/CalendarIntervalTriggerImpl.cs) trigger as it might be something close to what you want to do.

Comment: I don't know if you can make a cron trigger for those cases, but I'm pretty sure that you can use two cron triggers to cover them ("0 30 11 ? 1/1 MON#2 *" and "0 30 11 ? 1/1 FRI#2 *")